Custom formula for average deviation
I have a table in MS Excel with the following data, which will be loaded up until day 38 (from columns C to AN):



User/Day
1
2
3
4
5
Total (AO)
Average (AP)
Expected Average Deviation




User 1
32
34
34
28
38
166
33.20
2.56


User 2
26
26
24
52
25
153
30.60
8.56


User 3
21
40
10
12
40
123
24.60
12.32


User 4
12
25
27
40
28
132
26.40
6.32


User 5
34
30
36
44
40
184
36.80
4.16


User 6
34
37
28
30
26
155
31.00
3.6


User 7
22
30
36
24
39
151
30.20
5.64


User 8
20
53
24
34
44
175
35.00
10.8


User 9
31
53
34
37
42
197
39.40
6.48


User 10
26
43
18
30
41
158
31.60
8.32


User 11
35
31
51*
40
53
159*
31.80*
13.04*


User 12
55
34
47
29
18
183
36.60
11.52



An asterisk on user 11's day 3 means that he earned 51 points, but are invalid, so they should be counted as zero and will not count for their average points. This average is calculated in column AP with the formula =AO12/COUNTA(C12:AN12)).
I want to add a column which is the average deviation after the Average column, with the difference being that the value should be 0 if it finds a non-numeric character.
Logic says that AVEDEV should do the trick, but it counts the value as if there was no asterisk (ie, as a 51).
Is there any way I can do this?
Edit 1: expected average deviation added

What version of Excel are you using? (365, 2021 or earlier?)

(These answers require Excel 2019 or later; see the comments for things to try on earlier versions).
Simple option:
=AVEDEV(IF(ISNUMBER(C12:AN12),C12:AN12,0))

The formula applies a simple "if ISNUMBER(x) then x else 0" filter. We can pass the whole range in place of the variable x to get it to execute on each cell individually. Then AVEDEV acts on the resulting range.
Excluding blanks:
=AVEDEV(FILTER(IF(ISNUMBER(C12:AN12),C12:AN12,0),NOT(ISBLANK(C2:AN12))))

AVEDEV (and AVERAGE, etc.) usually exclude blank cells they are fed, but the first formula treats them as 0 instead. To preserve the exclusion, we can filter blanks using FILTER(x,NOT(ISBLANK(x)). By applying this between the IF and the AVEDEV above, we get this formula.
Brief option:
=AVEDEV(N(+C12:AN12))                                     (treats blanks as 0)
=AVEDEV(FILTER(N(+C12:AN12),NOT(ISBLANK(C12:AN12))))      (excludes blanks)

@MGonet below suggests this more specialised alternative, briefer for this case. The N function converts all inputs to numbers in a specific way, assigning general non-numerical data 0 while preserving numerical data (exact details). It can't natively be applied to a range as IF and ISNUMBER can, but the + operator in front of the range converts the range into an array behind the scenes, whence it works similarly to the first formula.
These would've been considered "array formulae" back in the day I think, but these days I suppose these functions can natively take arrays and operate on them cell-wise. EDIT: in fact, they are still array formulas, but they don't require Ctrl+Shift+Enter – more info.
For what it's worth, AVEDEV won't convert "51*" to 51, but rather will exclude that cell, taking the average across the remaining cells (so one fewer deviations are summed, then divided by one less).

If that was the case, the formula can be shortened to:
=AVEDEV(N(+C12:AN12))
The N function acts as a filter for numbers. + is needed due to the specificity of this function with respect to cell ranges.

@Pyoro That didn't seem to work, it shows a 0 as if the whole sum had an error (which might be caused by the asterisk somehow)

@HéctorIglesias Are you using a version of Excel from later than 2018? If not, can you try to enter the formula and then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of Enter? Click on the link in my answer for more info about this.

@MGonet Right you are; I'd never heard of "N". Sounds like witchcraft. I'll add it to the answer later, explain it and credit you, cheers.

Nevermind, I had typed the formula in the wrong cell. However, neither that formula nor the one provided by @MGonet give the correct result. I calculated what the AD would return for those 5 values if I did it cell by cell (although it's not efficient due to the high number of columns) and the returned values are not correct.

Give an example of the data and the result you expect for this data.

@MGonet just edited

Both formulas give results you expected.


It does for the range B:J, but moving the formulae to columns L and M and doing the range from B:K (to leave room for future results) does not give the correct result

The behavior of formulas when copied depends on the way arguments are addressed and is not related to the formula itself. If the formula in column L refers to the range B:F, and you want to copy the formula from column L to M so that it covers 1 more column, use the address $B4:F4. You should copy the cell, not move it.

@HéctorIglesias I added the option to exclude blank cells to my answer, thanks! Hope this explains it, MGonet.

That's what I had been wanting to get all week! Many thanks to both of you
